# Color a button in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, colors

I was trying to change the color of my button through scripting. I'm facing a weird problem.
if I write
button1.color = new Color(255, 0, 0);
It colors the button correctly. But if I change the color something like:
button1.color = new Color(237, 85, 59);
this, then it turns to ash or no color.
I'm new in unity and don't know where is the actual problem.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail to your question? Like the actual code you are using and e.g. screenshots of your Button component settings and how it looks like in the GameView etc

Comment: You should be using ```button1.GetComponent<Image>().color = desiredColor``` assuming that button1 is of type Button and all the components are as default.

Comment: @Ankit no actually not ... the `Button` component has a `colors` property which is a `ColorBlock` which overwrites the according `Image` color whenever the button state changes (normal, hovered, pressed, disabled) ... without further details it is hard to answer this question ;)

Comment: Isnt Color meant to be 0 to 1 and not 0 to 255? First one wouod be fine because it gives a full red, the other is likely a full black.

Answer (score 0):

The Color constructor takes in 4 values: red, green, blue and alpha. The values are between 0.0f and 1.0f, instead of

```
button1.color = new Color(237, 85, 59);
```

write something like

```
button1.color = new Color(0.93f, 0.33f, 0.23f, 1.0f)
```

The way to get the 0.0 - 1.1 values from the RGB 0 - 255 values is by **dividing the color values by 255**. Hope this answered your question.